# Date validation in visual basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, validation, date

I am attempting to get a true false boolean to return when I pass a date in a 10/28/2012 format, I have tried IsDate("10/28/2012") however when I do this it always returns false and this should actually return true, does anyone give me an idea as to what I am doing wrong, is there something I should do the the string perhaps before it gets passed into isDate?

Comment: `IsDate("10/28/2012")` returns `True` for me.  Are you sure that's the value you are passing to `IsDate`?

Comment: Can you pass like IsDate("#10/28/2012#")

Comment: A year doesn't have 28 months.  Try IsDate("28/10/2012")

Answer (score 2):

You should use `Date.TryParse(s as string, result as Date) As Boolean`

Where `s` is the string you're testing, and `result` is the Date you would like to store the parsed date in. If you do not care about the Date, and would only like to figure out if the value *is* a date, then you can just give it `new Date`. The function will return `True` if the parse succeeded, or `False` if it failed.